# HttpContext Problems in custom asp store

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am creating a custom ASP store and here is the problem presented as so:
Invitation Manager class:

```
public InvitationManager(InvitationStore store)
    {
        Store = store ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(store));
        UserManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }

public async void SendInvitation(Invitation inv, ApplicationUser SentTo)
    {
        var SentToUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(SentTo.Id);
        inv.SentTo = SentToUser;
        var SentBy = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Context.User.Identity.Name);
        inv.SentBy = SentBy.Id;
        var not = new Notification(Referenced_user: SentTo);
        inv.AssociatedNotification = not;
        SentToUser.Notifications.Add(not);
        await Store.CreateAsync(inv);
    }

public IQueryable<Invitation> Invitations
    {
        get
        {
            var queryableStore = Store.Invitations;
            if (queryableStore == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException("Can't access database invitations");
            }
            return queryableStore;
        }
    }

protected HttpContext Context
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current;
        }
    }

private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            if(_userManager == null)
            {
                _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
            }
            return _userManager;
        }
        set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

The application says that the dbcontext has disposed and I can't use it anymore. Moreover after some research I found out that I am maybe using different contexts for the same request which is this one who causes problems:

```
var SentBy = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Context.User.Identity.Name);
```

So how can I fix that? How to make them retrieve from the same context?

Comment: Provide the code of `UserManager` class, so we can understand how you are working with `DbContexr`

Comment: The UserManager code is the identity code that is preimplemented in ASP.Net. It's not mine it's microsoft preimplemented one.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43560105/861716) and the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still here is how is stored the dbcontext and it's relation with the UserManager :

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context) 
    {
        reurn new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
```

And i did exactly the same procedure for my Invitation Store i take the DbContext from the OwinContext wich has been declared at the application Startup.Auth.cs File. Wich get retrieved each time a user make an HTTP request.